# Unclear why UIView.animate works smoothly, but with code outside the animation block

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, imageview

I'm new to UIView animations & am having trouble understanding the execution of this logic.  I've created an ImageView to hold an image, I've added a Tap Gesture Recognizer, set the UIImageView to "User Interaction Enabled" & call an IBAction for that TGR.  Then I call the function below when the image is tapped.  The goal is to make the image 'pop' with a springy motion like it was punched, bouncing back to the image's original bounds so you can punch again.  It works exactly as I'd like (although I usually set withDuration to 0.25, I set it to 10 here to better see the animation).  However, I don't really understand why this works.  The last line smoothly sets the end bounds of the image to the original bounds size (which is what I want), but it does this smoothly EVEN THOUGH it's not part of the animation block in the closure.  If I eliminate the last line resetting the bounds for the image, the image will grow by 60 pixels in each direction after each execution (which is what I'd expect).  What I don't understand is: why does the last line in the function, self.imageToPunch.bounds = bounds, work smoothly and seemingly in conjunction with the animation block even if it's not inside that closure?

```
func animateImage() {

    // Create a variable holding the bounds of the image
    let bounds = self.imageToPunch.bounds

    // Setup and execute the animation
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.00, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [], animations: {
        self.imageToPunch.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - 60, y: bounds.origin.y - 60, width: bounds.size.width + 60, height: bounds.size.height + 60)

        }, completion: nil)

    // Reset the bounds of button so it doesn't grow (remember we spring 60 pixels from the corners)
    // self.imageToPunch.bounds = bounds
    self.imageToPunch.bounds = bounds
}
```

Comment: yes this is strange, i think when the animation starts the next value is set in the stack, so the animation thinks it has to finish the next one too. Well, i am not sure about that. If you want to understand your code, you should write a new UIView.animate with delay of your first animation, and change it back. It hink this is more secure and will work in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, Björn.  I'm not sure I follow the implementation you suggest, but it led me to try something else.  By shrinking the original image view bounds, then animating to return to the original size, that seems to produce the same effect.  Code is below, but I'd still really like to know why the original code was influenced by the line outside of the UIView.animate statement:

```
    // We'll use new constant bounds to hold the end state for the animation (imageToPunch's original bounds, or size rectangle)
    let bounds = self.imageToPunch.bounds

    // shrink imageToPunch by 60
    self.imageToPunch.bounds = CGRect(x: self.imageToPunch.bounds.origin.x + 60, y: self.imageToPunch.bounds.origin.y + 60, width: self.imageToPunch.bounds.size.width - 60, height: self.imageToPunch.bounds.size.height - 60)

    // animate image view out to the original size (saved in bounds) using a spring effect
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [], animations: {
        self.imageToPunch.bounds = bounds }, completion: nil )
```